# Error when command sudo apt-get install openssh-server..Package ssh is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I Wanted to install hadoop software on ubuntu 14.04 ..but when i try the command `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` I am getting the error as

```
Package ssh is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  openssh-client

E: Package 'ssh' has no installation candidate
```

I tried command `sudo apt-get update`, but still same problem arises ..Please help me..

Comment: You should consider asking this on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: Have it worked? Then mark the answer as 'correct', as it is customary in StackOverflow. It helps others in future in finding an answer for similar queries.

Comment: Hi, to install hadoop on ubuntu 14.04.. I am following this link http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php to install hadoop on ubuntu 14.04.. but i am stuck in this step..Format the New Hadoop Filesystem..Please help me..

Comment: Hi ,
when i type the command hadoop namenode -format on the terminal. I am getting error has hadoop not found ..please help me..

Comment: I'm afraid, installing specific applications(like Hadoop) on Ubuntu, doesn't fall particularly under the domain of StackOverflow. Please post a separate question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com). Also please be absolutely **specific** about error messages.